# Rails: How to create javascript object from controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3. I just want to create a simple javascript object from my controller. I don't want to render js because I'm already rendering html page and I want that javascript object in that html page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to make data from the controller available in javascript? Then you should use [JSON](http://www.json.org/). You can convert any ruby datatype into a json object with the .[to_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)

Since JSON is valid javascript you can do

```
var json_object = <%= @ruby_data.to_json %>;
```

Comment: what's the syntax if I for example I want to make @company available? I know I can do @company.to_json but that's not enough.

Comment: Is @company an ActiveRecord object? If so, it should work out of the box.

Comment: it's indeed an ActiveRecord object. Conversion works out of the box